# Question regarding holomorphic functions.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have seen this proposition : $f$ holomorphic then partial derivatives of $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are continous and satisfy Cauchy-Riemann (page 2 of [https://math.berkeley.edu/~vvdatar/m185f16/notes/Lecture-8_Cauchy_Riemann.pdf](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Evvdatar/m185f16/notes/Lecture-8_Cauchy_Riemann.pdf)).

But also to show that a function is holomorphic you can show that partial derivatives are continous and satisfy Cauchy Riemann.

My question : So the proposition is “iff” ?

Comment: Please choose a better title, compare https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144

Comment: Yes, for a function defined on $\mathbb C$ or on an open subset of $\mathbb C$  they are equivalent.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you.